# Error trying to start whonix : usupported configuration : quemu does not support the accel2d setting

Tags: libvirt, whonix

I'm trying to setup a whonix virtual machine but when I start the machine with `virsh -c quemu:///system start Whonix-Gateway` it just throws :

> unsupported configuration : qemu does not support the accel2d setting

Any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: I assume that was meant to be `-c qemu:///system`  and _not _ `quemu` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the video acceleration options from your definition

```
virsh -c qemu:///system edit Whonix-Gateway
```

This will fire up an editor (maybe `vi` or something else if you defined `$EDITOR`) with the XML definition.

In here search for the `video` section.  It may look *something* like

```
<video>
  <model type='vga' vram='8192' heads='1'>
     <acceleration accel3d='yes' accel2d='yes'/>
   </model>
</video>
```

The important line is the `<acceleration .../>` line.  Change the `yes` to `no` in both cases.   This will turn off acceleration.  Or you might just be able to delete the line.

In my case my section is

```
<video>
  <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
</video>
```

By using `virsh edit` the change will become valid immediately.  So now you should be able to do a `virsh start`